# Contract Interaction

Tags: solidity

Let's say we have a contract that implements a Priority Queue in Solidity that looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract PQ {
struct Node {
    int256 key;
    address value;
}    
Node[7] private heapKeyValue;   
function insert(int256 key, address addr) public {
      .. Implementation ..
}
function get_min() public view returns (int256) {
    return heapKeyValue[0].key;
}
function heapify(uint8 idx) internal {
      ..Implementation..
}
}
```

And another contract that uses this contract:

```
contract test_pq {
       function test() public returns (int256){
         PQ memory pq;
         for (uint8 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             pq.insert(i)
         return pq.get_min();
       }
}
```

Then what is the gas cost for calling the test() function in test_pq contract? Intuitively, the way I see it function state does not alter any state thus it should be zero gas cost. Is this the case?

Also I would appreciate if someone could explain to me what happens under the hood when the line `PQ memory pq` is executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions that do not alter any state do not consume gas unless they are called from contracts. The reason this is true is that if a function does not alters the state you can execute it in the node without actually doing a transaction, but this is not the case because `test` is calling insert whihc if the implementation refers to the name will likely change the state.

As for the line `PQ memory pq`, this will throw an error in solidity, you should do `PQ pq` this defines an object that you can use to access PQ methods.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My question is that ` PQ pq` is only a temporary variable in the function. As a result, any chance happening in this contract should not be persistent and thus it should not be stored in the blockchain. If the miner has access to the Priority Q contract/abi he can execute the whole function locally, without changing the blockchain at all.

Answer (score 1):

`test` calls `PQ.insert`. The answer to your question depends on the implementation of `insert`. If, like the name suggests, it inserts a `Node` in the queue, the state is changed. That means `test` will have to be called in a transction, which costs gas.

Answer (score 1):

No, `test` function would cost you gas. Only read operations don't cost any gas, the reasoning being that any node can just look it up in its storage section. In your `test`, you are running a loop and then `pq.insert` inserts `i` into your `heapKeyValue` variable. This does cost you gas.

As for `PQ memory pq`, let's read from the Solidity documentation: (more info [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-memory-keyword-what-does-it-do))

> The Ethereum Virtual Machine has three areas where it can store items.
>
> The first is “storage”, where all the contract state variables reside.
>   Every contract has its own storage and it is persistent between
>   function calls and quite expensive to use.
>
> The second is “memory”, this is used to hold temporary values. It is
>   erased between (external) function calls and is cheaper to use.

Local variables are referenced from "storage" by default, using keyword "memory" puts them in the context of "memory", i.e. a cheap ephemeral storage.