# contract interaction error: function should be payable

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

I apologize if it is a simple question. I tried to create a simple contract interaction. I've tried to follow instructions on `https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51760/contract-interaction`, docs, and another examples to create a simple contract interaction in solidity 0.5.16. There are two contracts, one is a hello-world contract, called `con_H` (H of "hello") and owns the `helloworld()` function. The other one is a contract "A" that calls the `helloworld` function of `con_H`. The point is that remix-ide throws an error that I find strange:
`call to con_A.fun_A1 errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.`

The code is the following one:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract con_H {
  function helloWorld() external pure returns (string memory) {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
}


contract con_A {
    con_H ins_H;
    
    function fun_A1() external view returns (string memory) {
        return ins_H.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

I've also tried for initial lines of con_A:

```
contract con_A {
    con_H ins_H = con_H(msg.sender);
    ...
}
```

with msg.sender address with enough balance of 100 test-ETH.

The only way I manage it to work is deploying aside con_H at a given direction `0x..123` and then force the instance H inside con_A with that exact address: `con_H ins_H = con_H(0x..123);`

How should be done? suggestions..?

Comment: In your first example, the `con_H ins_H` variable is not initialized, i.e., it is pointing to address 0. In your second example, it is wrongfully initializing, i.e., it is not pointing to an address where a `con_H` instance has been previously deployed.

Comment: You can do something like `con_H ins_H = new con_H();`, which will deploy a `con_H` instance internally when you deploy `con_A`. Alternatively, you can deploy a `con_H` instance yourself, and then pass its address to `con_A` when you deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

This (below) casts `ins_H` as Type: con_H but it doesn't instantiate it at an address. In case that isn't clear, it follows the same semantics as `uint x;` where `x` will always be cast as a `uint` but its *value* is still 0 because we haven't set it to anything else.

```
contract con_A {
    con_H ins_H;
    
    function fun_A1() external view returns (string memory) {
        return ins_H.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

So, far so good, but we have to assign an address to `ins_H` because it could be anywhere and there could be more than one. AS @goodVibration notes, your contract doesn't do it, so it's `address(0)` and that won't do. You can:

Pass it in when `con_A` is deployed (useful for deploying many `con_A` to connect to one `con_H`:

```
constructor (address h) public { // runs once on deployment
  ins_H = con_H(h); // notice we, again, cast the right-hand side as `con_H` to match the left
}
```

Kill two birds with one stone by deploying `con_H` when `con_A` is deployed. That works if there is 1:1 con_A:con_H.

```
constructor (address h) public {
  ins_H = new con_H(); // one-liner deploys AND stores the address of the instance
}
```

You can even change it:

```
function newCon_H(con_H h) public {
  ins_H = h;
}
```

You can also let your `con_H` be the hub in a hub & spoke arrangement and let it deploy as many `con_A` as it likes, and have them use the `msg.sender` to figure it out. I took the liberty of renaming a few things to make it closer to the style guide.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract ConH {
 
  event newConADeployed(ConA conA);
  
  function helloWorld() external pure returns (string memory) {
    return "Hello, World!";
  }
  
  function newConA() external returns(ConA a) {
      a = new ConA();
      emit newConADeployed(a);
  }
}

contract ConA {
    ConH insH;
    
    constructor () public {
        insH = ConH(msg.sender); // it's the hub
    }
    
    function fun_A1() external view returns (string memory) {
        return insH.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

You only need to "deploy" `ConH`. Then, use its `newConA()` function to deploy one of those from this simple "Factory" and then, in Remix, do ConA "At Address" where you give it the address of the contract the hub/factory made. That sort of structure can deploy lots of "spokes" that talk to one "hub."

I added the event emitter so you have a way to see that address - the little down arrow right of the blue transaction "Debug" button in the console output.

Hope it helps.